# Capitalize letters of a file

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files like this: "Name.Of.File.M01F03.csv" But sometimes users put the file like "Name.of.the.file.m01f03.csv"

How can i search in folders and rename(capitalize) first letter after the "." excepting extension from command line?
i use windows 2003 server.

Thank you.

Comment: There is  one letter in your example which is capital and is which is not after a period - does that need to be changed also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd c:\csv_dir
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set "oldName=%%~Na"
   set "newName="
   for %%c in ("!oldName:.=" "!") do (
      set "part=%%~c"
      set "char=!part:~0,1!"
      for %%d in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do set "char=!char:%%d=%%d!"
      set "newName=!newName!!char!!part:~1!."
   )
   ECHO ren "%%a" "_"
   ECHO ren "%%~DPa_" "!newName:~0,-1!%%~Xa"
)
```

Run this Batch file as test first; if the displayed `ren` commands are correct, remove the `ECHO` parts.

**EDIT**: *Second method added*

Previous Batch file also capitalize the first letter. If the first letter is right, then the method may be simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd c:\csv_dir
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set "name=%%~Na"
   for %%d in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do set "name=!name:.%%d=.%%d!"
   ECHO ren "%%a" "_"
   ECHO ren "%%~DPa_" "!name!%%~Xa"
)
```

Comment: Another little issue,what needs to be changed to capitalize the letter after "m03" in this case letter "f"? All those files are imported into a software and it need to be like "M01F03"

Comment: We need more info to do that. This change: is in the 4th. group in the name? Is in the last group before the extension? Is it ok if _all letters_ are changed in this group?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
pushd c:\csv_dir
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  set "filename=%%~nf"
  SET filename=!filename:.a=.A!
SET filename=!filename:.b=.B!
SET filename=!filename:.c=.C!
SET filename=!filename:.d=.D!
SET filename=!filename:.e=.E!
SET filename=!filename:.f=.F!
SET filename=!filename:.g=.G!
SET filename=!filename:.h=.H!
SET filename=!filename:.i=.I!
SET filename=!filename:.j=.J!
SET filename=!filename:.k=.K!
SET filename=!filename:.l=.L!
SET filename=!filename:.m=.M!
SET filename=!filename:.n=.N!
SET filename=!filename:.o=.O!
SET filename=!filename:.p=.P!
SET filename=!filename:.q=.Q!
SET filename=!filename:.r=.R!
SET filename=!filename:.s=.S!
SET filename=!filename:.t=.T!
SET filename=!filename:.u=.U!
SET filename=!filename:.v=.V!
SET filename=!filename:.w=.W!
SET filename=!filename:.x=.X!
SET filename=!filename:.y=.Y!
SET filename=!filename:.z=.Z!
REN "%%~nxf" "!filename!%%~xf"

)

popd
endlocal
```

Comment: I think akun wants just the first letter after the dot to be capitalized.

Comment: only the first letter after a dot has to be capitalized. For this `SET filename=!filename:.a=.A!` would work better.

Comment: Aaah.Thanks!Will fix that

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

I just did it as a personal test to see if that can be done without
showing the all alphabet.

It will take more time to do the job as the others solutions.

```
@echo off
pushd c:\csv_dir
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.csv) do (set $file="%%~na"
                       for /l %%f in (65,1,90) do (call:replace %%f)
                       REN "%%~nxa" "!$file!%%~xa")
endlocal
popd
exit /b

:replace
set $valmaj=%1
cmd /c exit %$valMaj%
set $valmaj=%=exitcodeAscii%
set $file=!$file:.%$valmaj%=.%$valmaj%!
```